# PromQL If condition and or operator

Tags: operators, prometheus, promql

in PromQL, I want to write

```
If metric_a>=bool 3:
  return metric_b
else:
  return 1
```

I am thinking to write as

```
(metric_b and metric_a>=3) or metric_a<bool 3
```

but I found that when I switch the metric order, like A or B, B or A, the query result would change, also am not sure if what I have means my if-else
why the or/and operator would give inconsist result? also what is a best way to present the if-else statement in here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your proposed solution:

```
(metric_b and metric_a>=3) or metric_a<bool 3
```

and it worked like expected, returning the value of metric_b when metric_a is >= 3, and 1 otherwise.

It's important to note that "VECTOR1 and VECTOR2" it's not necessarily equals to "VECTOR2 and VECTOR1". Take a look at the [Prometheus documentation about this](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators):

> vector1 and vector2 results in a vector consisting of the elements of
> vector1 for which there are elements in vector2 with exactly matching
> label sets. Other elements are dropped.

The results are always from the first vector of the "and" clause.

For example, the following query:

[image]

Gives a different result of the following one:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! but why the situation would change if I say "(metric_a>=3 and metric_b) or metric_a<bool 3"  or say "metric_a<bool 3 or (metric_a>=3 and metric_b)" will make the things different?

Comment: I just added more info.